# Max outgoing calls through single extension

Tags: twilio, phone-call

I would like to make calls to certain set (e.g 100) of phone numbers simultaneously and keep them connected/hold for a while. What is the minimum number of extensions do I need to buy from Twilio.

Bottom line what I am asking is how many simultaneous calls can a single extension make in twilio. We can put calls on hold and move onto the next number.

Answer (score 1):

According to their site, there is no limit, and you don't even need to buy a single number from them, you can use an existing verified number.

Twilio will however rate limit the number of outgoing calls made to 1 call per second.  Check out this link for more info:

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/what-are-the-limits-on-outbound-calls-and-sms-messages-per-second